# Disable cache HTML when charging a page

Tags: javascript, php, html, caching

I would like to know if it's possible to disable cache from navigator? When I change JS files, I have to do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to apply my changes. Did I miss something?

I tried using this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

Comment: Those look like they should work. But if the page has already been cached without those meta tags, adding them on the server won't do anything, since the browser keeps using the old, cached pages. There's no way to override past caching.

Comment: _"I tried using this"_ - that applies to your HTML file. It doesn't say anything about how caching for resources this document embeds, should be handled.

Comment: this code is implemented from the beginning and I always have to do CTRL + F5 to take into account the changes of my JS files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to disable it for development or debugging purposes, you can use the browser developer tools (F12) shown in the screenshots below for Chrome Version 111.0.5563.111 (Official Build) (64-bit). You can toggle/disable the browser cache. (this will only affect your browser)

[image]

And in the event your browser has already cached the app, you can clear out all the cached data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know this feature. But I'm looking to disable cache for everyone who uses my app. Not just for me in development.

Comment: just curious, does your app use a JS service worker?